# How to use closest and parents javascript methods to get td value in angular 6

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6, angular7

I am trying to get table tr and second td values using parents('tr) and closest('tr') javascript methods and after selected dropdown.But not working i have searched in google nut no use.If anyone know please help to find the solutions.

app.component.html:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Emp  id</td>
            <td>Roll id</td>
            <td>Action</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>12345</td>
            <td>18956</td>
            <td>12356</td>

            <td>
              <select (change)="getTdValue(e)">
                <option value="gettdvalue">Get second td value of this row</option> 
              </select> 
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>12345</td>
            <td>18906</td>
            <td>12356</td>

            <td>
              <select (change)="getTdValue(e)">
                <option value="gettdvalue">Get second td value of this row</option> 
              </select> 
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>12345</td>
            <td>98956</td>
            <td>12356</td>

            <td>
              <select (change)="getTdValue(e)">
                <option value="gettdvalue">Get second td value of this row</option> 
              </select> 
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>12345</td>
            <td>13956</td>
            <td>12356</td>
            <td>
              <select (change)="getTdValue(e)">
                <option value="gettdvalue">Get second td value of this row</option> 
              </select> 
           </td>
        </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

app.component.ts:

```
getTdValue(e){
    let target = e.target.closest('tr');
    if (target && target.id) {
        let td = target.find('td:nth-child(2)');
        if (td) {
             console.log("Second td value is ="+ td.value )
        } 

    }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-peioe6?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: You your checking if the target has an ID or not in your `if` statement, and since none of your `<tr>` elements have an ID, the logic inside the if statement will not be executed.

Comment: Also, the argument in `getTdValue(e)` should be `getTdValue($event)` if you want to hook to the `onchange` event.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to have a second `option` element inside your `select` element in order to get any change events triggered.

```
<select (change)="getTdValue($event)">
    <option></option> 
    <option>Get second td value of this row</option> 
</select>
```

Then you can rewrite your `getTdValue` method as follows:

```
getTdValue(mouseEvent: MouseEvent) {       
    let target = <HTMLSelectElement> mouseEvent.target;
    let td = <HTMLTableCellElement> target.closest('tr').childNodes.item(1); 
    console.log("This row ID is " + td.innerHTML);
}
```

See following [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cogans?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

**UPDATE**

When `target.closest` doesn't work (Angular 6), it can be replaced by `target.parentElement.parentElement` as follows:

```
getTdValue(mouseEvent: MouseEvent) {       
    let target = <HTMLSelectElement> mouseEvent.target;
    let td = <HTMLTableCellElement> target.parentElement.parentElement.childNodes.item(1); 
    console.log("This row ID is " + td.innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: Don't know actually, I worked on a fork of the Angular 8 StackBlitz you provided.

Comment: Getting  Error like : Can not read property 'closest' undefined

Comment: I made an update to my answer adding a solution that should also work for Angular 6.

Comment: I am using primeng table so I am not able to get closest tr..I can get only inside dropdown elements only i can access

Comment: I do not know why it is coming like this

Answer (score 0):

You have an if statement that evaluates the following condition: `target && target.id`. Since none of your `<tr>` element have an ID, the statement will evaluate to false, and none of the logic contained therein will be executed.

Since you are not using the ID for anything, you can simply remove it:

```
getTdValue(e){
    let target = e.target.closest('tr');
    if (target) {
        let td = target.find('td:nth-child(2)');
        if (td) {
             console.log("Second td value is ="+ td.value )
        } 

    }
}
```